# Sukkah decoration parameters

Tags: sukkot, sukkah, shiurim-measurements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can too many decorations render a sukkah invalid?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/can-too-many-decorations-render-a-sukkah-invalid)

What are all the rules concerning decorations that are hung overhead in a sukkah? In other words, within what measurements (height and width) does it need to be in order to avoid invalidating the s'chach, and to allow sitting directly underneath?

Comment: I'm not going to write up a whole answer, but the Nitei Gavriel discusses this in Chapter 21 of his laws of the Holiday of Sukkot, here: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46442&pgnum=145