# Must the entire decoration be within 4 t'fachim of the schach?

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements, schach

Inspired by [Can too many decorations render a sukkah invalid?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2715/5151)

If there is a big decoration hanging from the schach, is it OK as long as the top (part, or most of the decoration) is within 4 tefachim, or must the entire thing be within the 4? For example, the 2-foot-tall inflatable Chile pepper we like to hang. :)

Also, what about a paper chain? Certainly part of it is within 4, but if it is sufficiently long enough, it could dip down too low in the middle. (Trust me. :P) Is this a problem?

Comment: Try hanging your pepper over the table where no one sits. (Unless you have people sleeping there at night.)

Comment: @DoubleAA That is where we have it. It was just an example.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the entire thing has to be within 4 tefachim, but I'm not aware of any sources that say so. I think the poskim assumed that was obvious because it's always termed as 'anything that is 4 tefachim away', even only part of a something. (Plus, obviously, if it's hanging from the schach than there must be at least something that it's hanging on, though I guess you could ask about the case where the majority of it is within 4 and a minority hangs out)

Comment: @Matt But can you consider the string to be part of the decoration?

Comment: @DoubleAA "Try hanging your pepper over the table where no one sits.": You mean in front of where no one sits? Because if it's in front of a seat then that person will lean over the table (and anyway that may -- I don't know -- be a violation of _shulchano chutz lasuka_).