# How can i prevent schach from flying off in the wind?

Tags: how-to, schach

In the case of a heavy wind, is there any way to prevent the schach from simply flying away? It can be quite a pain if it falls down, in addition to the danger that it might get ruined.

Comment: I've heard that while tying down the schach itself is problematic, placing wooden beams on top and tying those down is permissible.  No source though.

Comment: @Ypnypn Please read the OP's "about me" on his profile.

Answer (score 4):

I have had the map rip when trying to tie it down but it has been kept well by putting slats on top of the mats over the entire length or width of the mats. That weighs it down without allowing it to pull apart.

Note that only a couple of slats are needed and it is the mat that makes the entire covering.

The mats need to have boards underneath to hold them up and the boards underneath will support the slats above the mat so that they will not fall through the mats.

Comment: This is a good idea, but we tried something like that one year, and the boards on top fell down.

Comment: @Scimonster the board above are also supported by the slats below so that they do not fall through. If the wind is so hard as to blow the top slats off then nothing would help.

Comment: @Scimonster put them perpendicular to the slats below.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bamboo mats on wooden slats (quite common), try looping the end of the mat around the slat, thereby hooking the schach on.

We had a nice storm this year, which would have totally brought down the schach if not for this. But as you can see here, it managed to hang in there. :)
[image: Interior of a sukka. One of the bamboo mats on top has had one of its corners fall in, but the opposite corner is suspended by the cross-slat that is stuck through the space between the last couple of bamboo strips.]
(Notice the [giant Chile pepper](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/46137/5151) in the middle. :))

Comment: What do you mean by looping the end of the mat around the slat?

Comment: As i have in the picture. The last couple lines of bamboo go under the slat, instead of sitting on it. I.e. the slat is inside the bamboo mat.