# Decorative tarp under schach

Tags: halacha, sukkot

Someone (Bucharan) told me that his Rabbi and his Rabbi's Rabbi say that you can put a [**decorative** tarp](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2715/5120) under the schah and it will remain kosher (even if rain cannot go through).

To me this feels wrong.

Is he correct? Sources please.

Comment: Doesn't the answer to that linked question already cover this?

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought blocking the rain is different. how is it not a house? the guy said  if he remembers correctly that the Rabbi  said some light can be seen

Comment: Like a house is kosher. Sukka 22a

Comment: @DoubleAA search for "rain" here https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/tzarich_iyun_schach/  , also see roofs that not mekabel tumma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thatching

Comment: @DoubleAA so it seems the main difference between a house and the sukka is that by a sukka the roof was put up recently

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is true from [here](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Building_the_Sukkah#cite_ref-45)

> If one places an artistic covering underneath his schach within four tefachim of the schach and his intention is to beautify the sukkah the sukkah is kosher. However, if the covering is placed above the schach or if it isn’t to beautify the sukkah, the sukkah is invalid

footnote 45 [ibid](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Building_the_Sukkah#cite_note-45)

> Shulchan Aruch [627:4.](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.627.4) Chazon Ovadia p. 84 writes that if one’s intention is to both beautify the sukkah and to protect oneself from the sun and rain the sukkah is kosher.

The source that even if it blocks the rain is Chazon Ovadia on Sukkot p. 84

[image: Chazon Ovadiah p84]
[image: Chazon Ovadiah p86]
[image: Chazon Ovadiah p87]

Comment: @Oliver thank you very much (if you post all this as an answer i will delete mine) please also add the next page (the end of foot note 13 seems to be important) Brocho Vhatslacha

Comment: how about I insert the next page but you do the rephrasing? :) (IMO, the next page isn't pertinent that much; OP did not say that there was intent to shield from rain)

Comment: @Oliver thank you I will try (I was the op and for me it is pertinent) maybe i will make it as a link not that as a photo

Comment: oh, didn't pay attention.

Comment: @Oliver so if you make an answer I will except it