# Sukkah underneath electric wires

Tags: sukkah, sukkot

If I build my sukkah underneath electric wires, is the sukkah kosher? Can I sit in the part of the sukkah that's underneath the wires?

Comment: How big are the wires?

Comment: Why would this be different from a wire holding decorations or anything else similar? consider the extension cord running over the schach to the light fixture in the succah.

Comment: @sabahillel: Decorations are [batel to the schach if they're within 4 tefachim of the schach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2715/69). I'm discussing a situation here where a telephone and/or electric wire that feeds your house is runs across your yard and is high above your sukkah.

Comment: @Chanoch You should edit that into your question, as well as why you think these are any better than, say, overhanging tree branches of the same width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the second from the right, second from the top cartoon on [this "Hilchot Sukka 2" poster](https://www.sukkah.com/itemdetail.cfm?ProductId=2930), a similar case involving clotheslines is fine, even if there are multiple lines running near each other (though there are those who are stringent about it).

Sources cited:

- [Mishna Berura 626:17](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=173) with Sha'ar Hatzion ad loc.
- [Mishna Berura 632:20](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=195) with Sha'ar Hatzion 632:16
- Halichot Shelomo (precise citation to be deciphered)
- [Minchat Yitzchak 8:56](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=1600#p=408&fitMode=fitheight&hlts=&ocr=)

Comment: To clarify there is only a svara to be stringent if there are multiple strings within 3 tephachim of each other which may or may not combine through lavud into a larger item which would be considered a roof.

Comment: @user6591 If you've already worked through the sources, please feel free to add more detail to this post before I B"H do.

Answer (score 2):

[Yalkut Yosef 629:34](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_31.html#HtmpReportNum0004_L2):

> סוכה שנעשית תחת חבלי כביסה, או חוטי חשמל וטלפון, אפילו אין בין חבל לחבל שלשה טפחים, אין לפסול מטעם לבוד, אלא הסוכה כשרה. ואפילו אם תלו כביסה על החבלים אין בכך כלום והסוכה כשרה.

A sukkah that is built under clothes lines, or electric or telephone wires, even if there are less than three tefachim between adjacent wires, does not pasul the sukkah because of *lavud*, rather the sukkah is kosher. Even of you hang clothes from the clothes lines, this is not a problem, and the sukkah is still kosher.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple lines which are within three tefachim of each other, they are considered to be a closed solid area of schach pasul, which could then theoretically disqualify your sukka, depending on where it is situated above your sukka

Comment: This answer would be a great deal more valuable if you could add in sources to back up its assertion.